# JS to dynamically show/hide div for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form being generated in rails that allows the user to add as many instances of the object as they want with a "Add Object" button. Each instance of the object displays the same form. I would like that form to display a field dynamically when they choose a specific option in the select input.

The issue I'm having with my current JS is that when I change my select input on one form, the rest of the forms on the page reflect the change. I need the JS to only reflect the change on the form being modified.

```
# HTML
<form id=edit_application>
    <div class="fields">
        <select class="asset_type">
            <option value="Machinery">Machinery</option>
            <option value="Equipment">Equipment</option>
            <option value="Property">Property</option>
        </select>
        <div class="Machinery">
            # input field
        </div>
        <div class="Equipment">
            # input field
        </div>
        <div class="Property">
            #input field
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fields">
        <select class="asset_type">
            <option value="Machinery">Machinery</option>
            <option value="Equipment">Equipment</option>
            <option value="Property">Property</option>
        </select>
        <div class="Machinery">
            # input field
        </div>
        <div class="Equipment">
            # input field
        </div>
        <div class="Property">
            #input field
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Each instance of the object's form is wrapped in

```
<div class="fields"></div>.
```

The gem I'm using to generate the nested object forms in rails provides a trigger that I'm using (nested:fieldAdded) to run the JS function when a new instance is added.

```
    $(function() {
      $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
        $(".property").hide();
        $(".equipment").hide();
        $(".machinery").hide();
      });
    });

    $(function() {
      $('.asset_type').on('change', function () {
          $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
              if($(this).attr("value")=="Property"){
                  $(".property").show();
                  $(".equipment").hide();
                  $(".machinery").hide();
              }
              if($(this).attr("value")=="Machinery"){
                  $(".machinery").show();
                  $(".property").hide();
                  $(".equipment").hide();
              }
              if($(this).attr("value")=="Equipment"){
                  $(".property").hide();
                  $(".equipment").show();
                  $(".machinery").hide();
              }
          });
      }).change();
    });
```

My logic behind the function above is that when a new instance of the object is added, the fields should be hidden. When the user changes the select input, the result should show the proper div, and make sure the other ones are hidden, however when a select input is changed to 'Property', it shouldn't change all of the fields being shown for every form on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like below .  on change get [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) div of select box which have class 'fields'. now  you have object of element which is parent of all this  'property', 'equipment','machinery' inside 'fields'. here with jquery [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function you can find child element within specific parent element.

you also check [Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach event to dynamically  created element. [Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/j754envd/1/)

```
 $(function() {
  $(document).on('change','.asset_type',function () {
     var OBJ = $(this).parent('div.fields')
      if($(this).val()=="Property"){
          OBJ.find(".Property").show();
          OBJ.find(".Equipment").hide();
          OBJ.find(".Machinery").hide();
      }
      if($(this).val()=="Machinery"){
          OBJ.find(".Machinery").show();
          OBJ.find(".Property").hide();
          OBJ.find(".Equipment").hide();
      }
      if($(this).val()=="Equipment"){
          OBJ.find(".Property").hide();
          OBJ.find(".Equipment").show();
          OBJ.find(".Machinery").hide();
      }
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: I'm still trying to solve this issue. To further debug, I added a console.log to each if block to make sure it was selecting the right value- it is. However, the show() and hide()'s aren't working. I'll put my code if a fiddle and share to debug further. Thank you for your help so far

Comment: if possible provide fiddle. i wll check why hide show not working .

Comment: @Questifer alos i have update my answer and add one new option in code

Comment: @Questifer  may be i found issue . in html you give class name which start with caps "Machinery","Equipment","property" and in show hide code you use in in small letter.  check will apply same name

Comment: @Questifer check my updated code class starts with caps . it will work

Comment: You're right the demo works perfectly. When I posted the Q, I simplified my form code (didn't think it would impact the answer). However, the DOM tree looks like: <div class="fields><div class="col-md-6"><section><div class="row"><div class="col col-6><label><select class="asset_type>. That would mean I just need to change the parent() method you're using with a method to locate the closest div above with class="fields", correct? I'll mark your answer correct nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: I changed var OBJ = $(this).parent('div.fields') to var OBJ = $(this).closest('div.fields').

Answer (score 1):

i made a slight change to the html so you could tell which input field you are looking at. Inside the change function of the asset_type option I get the fields div that is closest. I use that reference to filter which div you want to show

## HTML

```
<form id=edit_application>
    <div class="fields">
        <select class="asset_type">
            <option value="Machinery">Machinery</option>
            <option value="Equipment">Equipment</option>
            <option value="Property">Property</option>
        </select>
        <div class="Machinery">
            # machinery input field
        </div>
        <div class="Equipment">
            # equipment input field
        </div>
        <div class="Property">
            # property input field
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fields">
        <select class="asset_type">
            <option value="Machinery">Machinery</option>
            <option value="Equipment">Equipment</option>
            <option value="Property">Property</option>
        </select>
        <div class="Machinery">
            # machinery input field
        </div>
        <div class="Equipment">
            # equipment input field
        </div>
        <div class="Property">
            # property input field
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

## JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
        $(".property").hide();
        $(".equipment").hide();
        $(".machinery").hide();
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('.asset_type').on('change', function () {
        var foo = $(this).closest(".fields");
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="Property"){
                $(foo).children(".Property").show();
                $(foo).children(".Equipment").hide();
                $(foo).children(".Machinery").hide();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="Machinery"){
                $(foo).children(".Property").hide();
                $(foo).children(".Equipment").hide();
                $(foo).children(".Machinery").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="Equipment"){
                $(foo).children(".Property").hide();
                $(foo).children(".Equipment").show();
                $(foo).children(".Machinery").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, although i would use the `.fields`-selector in closest: `var foo = $(this).closest(".fields");`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I edited my reply to reflect it

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$(.className).show()` it's going to show or hide all elements with that class name. Maybe you should generate some ids for the elements you wish to hide. Something like `<div class="Machinery" id="Machine1">` so then your JS could be

```
if($(this).attr("value")=="Machinery"){
      $("#Machine1").show();
      $("#prop1").hide();
      $("#equip1").hide();
}
```

Comment: The instances of the object are generated dynamically by the gem and have several digits appended to them (ex. id="Machine3123432432X"). I can't plan to know what the ID's will be ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your problem, but here is what I would do:

Assuming your scenario is the need to create N objects dynamically based on user interaction, and later manipulate these objects/their properties. If the code that creates the new form instance creates html objects with the exact same IDs or classes or whatever css selector you may be willing to use to address a specific element or object, then, indeed, referencing a given html element ID or a class will end up selecting all of such existing elements, in all forms, because their css selector is exactly the same. So, the simplest solution is to have a counter that is incremented every time a new instance of the form is generated.

This counter must be used when naming the wrapping div "fields" in the form.

Consider a user has just clicked on whatever input option that triggers the creation of a new form - assuming this is the 3rd time the user does so, you would end up with the following:

```
<div class="fields1">
<div class="fields2">
<div class="fields3">
```

In your "change" event handlers, you would then need to determine the selector dynamically, using the counter value to reference the corresponding form object.

So if you want to reference the "Machinery" input field, you would address

```
$(".fields" + counterValue + " .Machinery").val()
```